# SQL procedimiento almacenado con cantidad de filtros variables

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedure

tengo un procedimiento almacenado con una tabla creada por varios inners, y lo que necesito es pasarle entre 1 y 4 parámetros para formar el where de la consulta. Lo que no me estoy dando cuenta es si quiero pasarle 2 solo de los 4, que los otros no me los pida dentro del procedimiento...

Gracias!

Comment: Revisa [ask] y mejora tu publicación

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas es poder generar una [consulta dinamica](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). a tu procedimiento deberías mandar siempre todos los parámetros, pero tener un identificador con el cual validaras si un parámetro se agregar al where:

En el siguiente ejemplo utilizo como identificador el caracter " * " para identificar cuando no se aplicara el where:

```
create procedure SpConsultaDimanica
@parametro varchar(25)
as
begin
    declare @sql nvarchar(max),@where nvarchar(max)
    set @sql='
    select campo1, campo2 from tabla
    '
    if @parametro<>'*'
        begin
            set @where='where campo1='+@parametro
        end

    set @sql=@sql+@where

    exec sp_executesql @sql
end
```

espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: se te agradece el apoyo pero deberías esperar a que el OP mejore su pregunta añadiendo el código tratado o lo que ha investigado